# How can I delete certain lines of a text file using python?

Tags: python, txt

I have a fairly long text file and want to delete cerain chunks of it. Is it possible that I can delete cerain lines between certain sections of text?
So I have some lines which are consistent in all my PDF's and want to detele text between certain sentences, how can I do this?

Currently dont really know where to start with this issue, since I am new to python. Unfornately I cannot share my text file since its all confidential client information

Comment: What is the format of the input file, and how are the lines specified (perhaps by line number, or offset from start)?

Comment: Is it a text file or a PDF? How do you identify those lines that you want to remove/omit? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Make your question clear

Comment: Hi so it is currently in a txt file which I have converted questionarie from a PDF, so currently there are no line identifiers, they are just a list of questions and answers. However, I want to remove certain questions and their corresponding response's since they are not required for what I want right now. 

So far I was thinking of creating a keyword file and removing all strings/lines which contain those keywords. But I thought if I could just delete chunks between lines which contain certain text (which will stay consistent in every questionairre) then this would be more helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately the line numbers will change depending on the questionnaire and the responses so I think this has to be text specific. There are line numbers though, if thats helpful

Comment: if you used a csv file instead of converting a text file to a PDF, you can more easily remove rows...

Comment: I am not converting to a pdf, it is currently a txt, so could convert to a csv file